# How to Solve an Arrival Rate for a given Latency Percentile?

Tags: queueing

I've been cranking on this for some time and think some help would be nice.

Say I've got an M/M/1 queue, and while I can't change my service time distribution, I can certainly adjust my arrival rate.  If I wanted my latency to stay within a threshold T with probability Pct, how do I solve for this?

To keep this reasonable, say I have a minimum service time M.  Here's where I am:

$$ \Sigma^{(T/M)}_{k=1} P(Erlang(k,\lambda) < T) = Pct $$

Where k iterates over all the potential queue lengths.  So, I have two questions from here:

1. Have I already screwed up?
2. Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Alternatively stated: I'd adjust $\lambda$ by adding more servers to do the work (evenly dividing the work across $k$ servers each getting $\lambda/k$ arrivals), and a load balancer up front.  So, one could also ask to solve k in an M/M/k queue to keep the response time < T with probability Pct.  Not that I know how to do it that way either :(

Thanks in advance!